# AngularJS multiple select elements can not have the same value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm quite new to AngularJS and I'm trying to define 4 seperate select elements usign element directives.

```
app.directive('playerselect', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/player-select.html',
    }
});

<select ng-options="player.full_name for player in players">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Kies een speler</option>
</select>
```

When a user selects an option in one of the select elements I want the other select elements to be updated, so that the selected option gets disabled in all other select elements. Basically, I want to make sure that each option can get chosen only once.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

*directive*

```
app.directive('playerSelect', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: ...
        scope: {
            players: '=',
            selectedPlayer: '=',
            selectedPlayers: '=',
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.isDisabled = function(player) {
                return $scope.selectedPlayers.indexOf(player) > -1 &&
                       player !== $scope.selectedPlayer)
            };
        },
    }
});
```

*directive template*

```
<select ng-model="selectedPlayer">
  <option ng-repeat="player in players" ng-disabled="isDisabled(player)">{{player}}</option>
</select>
```

*controller*

```
app.controller('PlayerController', function($scope) {
    $scope.players = ...
    $scope.selectedPlayers = [
        $scope.player1,
        $scope.player2,
        $scope.player3,
        $scope.player4,
    ];
});
```

*controller template*

```
<div ng-controller="PlayerController">
  <player-select players="players" selected-players="selectedPlayers" selected-player="player1"></player-select>
  <player-select players="players" selected-players="selectedPlayers" selected-player="player2"></player-select>
  <player-select players="players" selected-players="selectedPlayers" selected-player="player3"></player-select>
  <player-select players="players" selected-players="selectedPlayers" selected-player="player4"></player-select>
</div>
```

Comment: So there's no way to do this using `ng-options`?

Comment: @CasCornelissen the problem is using ng-options with ng-disabled. You could possibly use ng-options and instead of disabling the options you remove them from the players list, that might be better UX also.

Comment: ah I understand. Thanks for the answer, I'll see which path I'll choose.

Comment: @materik glad i could help. please select this as the approved answer if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

**Check this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msrbapp2/)</kbd>** for see it in action.

I would recommend you an use of [directive two way data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

So in your html :

```
<player-select players="players" ng-model="select1"></player-select>
<player-select players="players" ng-model="select2"></player-select>
<player-select players="players" ng-model="select3"></player-select>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.players = [{
    name: 'foo'
}, {
    name: 'bar'
}, {
    name: 'baz'
}];
```

And the directive, using `scope.$watch` for update each list :

```
angular.module('fiddleApp').directive('playerSelect', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            players: '='
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="player.name for player in     playersCopy"></select>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {

            function update() {
                scope.playersCopy = angular.copy(scope.players);
                if (scope.selected) {
                    scope.playersCopy.push(scope.selected);
                }
            }

            scope.$watch('selected', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    scope.players.splice(scope.players.map(function (a) {
                        return a.name
                    }).indexOf(newValue.name), 1);

                    if (oldValue) { scope.players.push(oldValue); }

                    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.selected);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('playersUpdate');
                }
            });

            scope.$on('playersUpdate', function () {
                update();
            });

            update();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to disable them (`disabled` attribute on the option) instead of removing them?

Comment: Yup, but as @materik said you will not be able to use ng-options on `select`